# HTML Input shown in alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Evening all,

I am starting out with JQuery/ Javascript and am having some trouble taking an input and making the content show up in an `alert()`.

This is what I have written so far -

```
$(function(){
var input = $('#input').val();

    alert(input);
});
```

The HTML info is

```
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Input here">
```

If someone can shed some light as to wear I'm going wrong, it would be much appreciated

Comment: This will not output to console

Comment: Would work if you had set a value `<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Input here" value="123">` but usually you wait for user input in that field

Comment: what is the goal? your code is fine, but what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code will run when you load the page, You need to bind your code to something like a button or a `change`,`keyup` or something else.

Like this

```
$(function() {
  $("#input").change(function() {
    var input = $('#input').val();

    console.log(input);
  })
});
```

**demo change event**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#input").change(function() {
    var input = $('#input').val();

    console.log(input);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Input here">
```

**demo keyup event**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#input").keyup(function() {
    var input = $('#input').val();

    console.log(input);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Input here">
```

Look at this page explaining jquery [Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer explains why and what you can do about it. Let my just add that most probably, you will want some submit button so the code that handles that input value will run only after you have clicked that button. In such case you can do it like this.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  alert(input.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Input here">
<button>submit</button>
```